# Rules for "I'm Not Dead Yet!" trophy

Tags: achievements, mortal-kombat-9

I have been trying to get this MK trophy for a while now I've seen a lot of forums discussing how to get it but the conditions are never clearly stated...

How exactly do I get this trophy? I have heard that I need to be on 10%> but does the opponent need to be on full health?

What are the conditions needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To earn the "I'm Not Dead Yet!" achievement, you need to perform a comeback (win) in an online ranked match where you have less than 10% of your HP remaining, and your opponent has close to (or exactly, it's somewhat debated) 100% of their HP remaining.

Source: [Here.](http://www.trueachievements.com/a149353/im-not-dead-yet-achievement.htm)